# Filter messages in Android Studio debug console

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, console

I use breakpoints, which generate messages in debug console (**not logcat!**). Unfortunately debug console also contains a lot of other messages, for example, tons of

> D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0xb45d4700,w=720,h=1280)

How can I leave only messages from breakpoints?

Below is the console I talk about. Again - it's not logcat.
[image]

Answer (score 28):

Right click on the line you want to hide, on the popup menu click "Fold lines like this". You'll be prompted a window where you can edit the folded lines content.

Ps. Folded lines content work the way `contains` string method does.

Comment: Thank you, very useful feature! But what about filter like in logcat?

Comment: Works pretty much the same way, you can still fold lines, but in logcat theres also a Filter Configuration in the right corner which includes regex filtering, filtering based in Tags, Message content, Package name, Log level..

Comment: @Alexey .. I use both of them and create/modify the regex filter when I'm debugging something very specific

Comment: How to find list of fonded lines?