# How do I trace and resolve Android App's BLASTBufferQueue Faking releaseBufferCallback?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, logcat

I've recently begun building my first app using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. Up to now, I have not seen this error show in the Logcat and due to my lack of experience, I'm stumped! I was cleaning up code, extracting functions to other class files, cleaning up the UI for one the the Composables I made and now I'm getting constant Logcat entries for the BLASTBufferQueue with the following entry:

```
14:03:10.687  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
14:03:10.687  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
14:03:10.704  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
14:03:10.704  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
14:03:10.722  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
14:03:10.722  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
14:03:10.738  E  [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:3) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
```

This is occuring on every recomposition it seems, but I don't know what I changed to cause it.

Is this code related?

It doesn't seem to be an issue when using the emulator, currently a Resizable API 33.

But does appear when using on a physical device, a Pixel 7 Pro.

Now, on the physical device, I did update it with the December update (Build number: TQ1A.221205.011) since I last worked on my app. Could something have changed with the update to cause these Logcat entries?

Comment: I came to post this same question. These logcat entries began appearing on my Pixel 7 after applying the same December 2022 update. My app is several years old but it is still in active development. It targets API 33 and is written entirely in Java, with no recent significant changes. It is likely something related to the update that is so new that it hasn't gotten a lot of attention yet.

Comment: @mike47 I just realized I put a Pixel 6 when I'm using the Pixel 7. Corrected the post. So it seems like it may be device related, at least looking at the device being the common factor here.

Comment: I'm also getting hundred lines of this on Pixel 6.

Comment: Same thing for me on Pixel 6 Pro after recent update on device

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not sure where it comes from, but for now I'm hiding them from logcat by adding `-tag~:BLASTBufferQueue` to the logcat filter input field after `package:mine`.

Comment: Same thing, I'm on Pixel 6 Pro as well

Comment: @KennethSaey Awesome idea! I'll be doing that tonight, didn't even know how to filter like that. Thank you adding how you do it, very helpful!

Comment: From the CLI: `adb logcat BLASTBufferQueue:S` (where `S` means silent)

Comment: Same here, I get the error messages on my Pixel 6, Android 13, Build-Number: TQ1A.221205.011. 
I don't get the error messages on my Pixel 4, Android 13, Build-Number: TP1A.220624.014. And I don't use JetpackCompose.

Comment: Getting this on my Pixel 5 as well.

Comment: Running prototype TensorFlow Object Detector.   On a Pixel6, this error occurs continuously as soon as I bring up the Object Detector (mod of TF example project).  On Samsung Galaxy A7 Lite tablet, this error does NOT occur.  I assumed it had to do with the TF implementation but it appears to be device specific.

Comment: Same problem on Pixel 5, is it Google engineer forget to disable log??

Comment: @ahandapp if I remember right, the Pixel 5 doesn't run on tensor and Alan Lu has the log error popping up. Perhaps it is a Google Device issue? The Pixel 5 would still get the monthly updates & would have the current one that both myself, Sceada, and mike47 have on our Pixel 7. Sceada already confirmed it doesn't happen on his Pixel 4, their last update was Nov. 2022, but his Pixel 6 is getting the error running Dec. 2022 update.

Comment: @Dolanj, strong probability it is device/OS/build specific.  Interestingly, I used the Logcat tag: ^(?!(BLASTBufferQueue)) to hide the flood of logcat messages which usually was fine.  However, an app doing Artistic Style Transfer on a video stream with many transitions between listeners crashes with no other error message except the BLASTBufferQueue message - so it's NOT entirely benign.

Comment: Same here, looks like it seems to be an issue after the December update as my app's camera viewfinder will freeze whenever this message is logged.
Pixel 6

Comment: I am also getting the same logs in my Pixel 6 Pro.

Comment: I'm seeing on new Android app in kotlin, but I'm not using compose.  I don't believe it's related to Compose.  The koltin UI is really basic at the moment, but it's talking to bunch of native libraries though.  I'm on a Pixel 6.  I'm not using TensorFlow.  Reading the other comments, seems like its Pixel devices with Android 13.

Comment: @johngray1965 I agree it being pixel devices also, and I believe it is related to the December 2022 update since it was after that update is when it started. Still not sure what it is but ahandyapp did find a use case for the log entry though so it's there for a reason.

Comment: I have the same thing happening on my Pixel 6 while developing a flutter app

Comment: I have the same problem on my pixel 7 pro

Comment: For Android Studio: Right click on the line or select the characters you want to hide. On the popup menu click "Fold lines like this". You'll be prompted a window where you can edit the folded lines content.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709658/filter-messages-in-android-studio-debug-console

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here are some of the findings I got related to this issue.

## 1) What is BlastBufferQueue?

I believe this must be happening in Android S and above and that too after december update 2022.
`BlastBufferQueue` is kind of message queue, where the geometry of the app layout window changes ,it will be submitted to Android platform's surface renderer. The buffers sent by multiple application will be synchronized.

Prior to Android S , the changes will be posted through `Transaction`. Here the buffers are not synchronized when they are sent from multiple app process.

This BlastBufferQueue helps to open up connection between buffers sent from multiple app process.

**Links to know more about BBQ:**

https://www.jianshu.com/p/50a30fa6952e

https://www.jianshu.com/p/cdc60627df90

[image]

Here is the below code where the blastbuffer is getting update from `ViewRootImpl`.

[image]
[Source Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java)

## 2) Root cause of the log.

I got able to find the commit where this particular log is added.

[Link to Commit](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/native/+/405e2f68fbe2992e3b06f1f0a55df331d5150a64)

This was a fix for issue where ANR occurred where the view transactions gets updated but the buffer callback was never released(In some cases). So this commit was workaround to fake releasing the buffer callback, when `TransactionCompleteCallback` is completed.

[image]

In this commit , it has been mentioned that it was a safe work around. The root issue linked in commit is private.
This is the commit change where android team have added to fake release the buffer callback. This reason you might be getting this log.

> <s>Finally, to summarise this log can be safely ignored.</s>

**EDIT:**
I see some people having fatal crashes because of this due to some overflow. We have to wait for a fix for the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271675642) raised by Greg.
Temporarily , the logs can be made silent in Logcat Window. Please refer to the comments under the Question.

Comment: That's interesting info to know on this subject! One of the comments above from @ahandyapp mentions he has a crash and the BlastBufferQueue log entry is the only thing he gets, "However, an app doing Artistic Style Transfer on a video stream with many transitions between listeners crashes with no other error message except the BLASTBufferQueue message - so it's NOT entirely benign." Based off your answer though, it seems that the crashes he is experiencing may be unrelated to the BlastBufferQueue. Also, the BBQ entry started on Android 13 after the Dec 2022 update, prior to Dec it didn't fire.

Comment: Yes. I also think the same. The crash might be of different issue I guess.

Comment: Thanks for this investigation! I've filed an Android issue for this log spam, since there didn't seem to be one yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271675642

Comment: "can be safely ignored"
Except it's logged AT ERROR LEVEL. And tons of copies are logged. WTH! This is not what working software should behave like.

Comment: As for crashes - I got Android Studio Dolphin crash today related to the issue. It looks like Logcat window got some kind of overflow, because I stuck on the page, which generated a lot of BLASTBufferQueue spam for some time ant it happened.

Comment: Haha, ignoring a storm of logs... What about performance?! Unless `Log.e()` is stripped by Proguard/R8 (and `LOGE()` for native code), there will be a significant impact.

Comment: seems to be fixed. I no longer have a slew of BlastBufferqueue errors filling my logcat.  Must've been the April update?