# Android CameraApi2 BLASTBufferQueue

Tags: android, camera-api

I am working on a android app with the cameraApi2. It is working fine which means I see a preview of the camera and I can take pictures.
The only problem I have is the logs getting flooded with the following error message:

```
E/BLASTBufferQueue: [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:2) Faking releaseBufferCallback from transactionCompleteCallback
```

I already googled for the error message but did not find any explanation.
Can somebody explain what this one actually means so i can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate Question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722563/how-do-i-trace-and-resolve-android-apps-blastbufferqueue-faking-releasebufferca


please refer this link for resolution